# cmd line app for encryption via std in/out/error?

Tags: encryption, command-line

Now that i am thinking about it, it seems unusual that i dont know.
Is there an app that allows me to encypt data with std in/out/error? perhaps something like

```
appname -c AES -k MyTextKey (or -kh for a key made from hex data) -o stdout -i stdin
```

I never bothered learning how to use one outside of .NET and it would be annoying to do it for each language. Signing would be good too

```
appname -s salt_text -in file.blah -o key.sig
```

On windows but i'd like a linux solution as well.

-edit- gpg does not look like a solution. I looked but cant see how to encrypt something with cipher using a password and not use public/private keys which seem to be the only way it can encrypt.

Comment: No a programming question, now, is it? Off to superuser.com with you!

Comment: GNUPG. BUt this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `openssl` for this.

Answer (score 0):

On most linux flavors you can use gpg.

[GPG website](http://www.gnupg.org/)

Comment: GPG looks more like rsa, pub/prv keys and name of users rather then encryption (symmetrical) with passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example in .net of the GnuPG calls wrapped in managed .net code. The encryption / decryption occurs by writing / reading to the console process using streamreader / streamwriter calls.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/gnupgdotnet.aspx

Comment: GnuPG doesnt look like i can encrypt with AES without a public key

Comment: You never mentioned a specific cryptographic method to use and therefore AES / public key was not considered.